# Alternate Solution for Creating Drive-time Shape Files?

Tags: gis, geospatial, esri

`Esri` has a number of tools that will produce a `drive time polygon` around a point.  Unfortunately, I don't have an Esri subscription and have already used their trial subscription.

Is there an alternative to Esri that can calculate a `drive time polygon` with the means of exporting that polygon as a `shape file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many alternatives to ESRI. You can use

- GRASS v.net.iso
- pgRouting and QGIS
- PostGIS
- ...

I recommend you to read this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/creating-drive-time-polygons-using-open-source-tools

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to gis.stackexchange -- found a couple of solutions to try.